# Angular RxJS sequential requests issue

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following requests;

```
  public userLogin(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.apiURL}/login `, {username, password}, constants.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        map((response) => {
          this.setToken(response.token);
        })
      );
  }

  public getUser() {
    return this.http.get<IUser>(`${this.apiURL}/api/account`)
      .pipe(
        map((user: IUser) => {
          sessionStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
          this.userSubject.next(user);
        })
      );
  }
```

I would like to call them sequentially and check the returned value of the last request.
I implemented the following block of code however, the `console.log` output is `undefined` within the `subscribe` section.
In the network tab, I can see that both requests are called sequentially and there's no error.

```
this.authService.userLogin(username, password).pipe(
        concatMap(() => { return this.authService.getUser() })
      ).subscribe((res: any) => {
        console.log(res);
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (err.status === 401) {
          console.log('sign-in page - 401');
          this.unauthorized = true;
        }
      });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of a good reason to specify return types in TypeScript.  If you had you'd realize that the result of the **map** operator in **getUser** is always undefined.  In this case I think you want to use **tap** which allows you to perform a side-effect while passing the source emission further through the stream.

```
public getUser(): Observable<IUser> {
  return this.http.get<IUser>(`${this.apiURL}/api/account`).pipe(
    tap((user: IUser) => {
      sessionStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
      this.userSubject.next(user);
    })
  );
}
```

You probably want to use **tap** in **setToken** as well if you intend on returning the token value from that method.

Answer (score 0):

The `map` operator on your `getUser` Observable doesn't return anything. Have it return what the Observable is supposed to emit, and you'll get something in the response.

Also, putting logic in a `subscribe` callback is not best practice. Use  `tap` to implement side effects.